# adding XML line breaks on coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion, line-breaks

Currently I'm creating a XML file from SQL query. The file is generated successfully, but it generates an enormous length of text on a single when I open it in notepad. Is there any way to add lines after and before XML tag? or is there something I miss?

Comment: You mean formatting the XML?

Comment: What if you open it in a web browser?

Comment: @DanBracuk is correct!. Doesn't matter how it appears in the notepad as long as it doesn't show any errors when you tend to open it in browser!

Comment: Why do you want to add formatting (lines) to the XML? Usually XML content is used to communicate with other systems and not used as content to be read by humans. I've noticed the same with XML generated by SQL, but never bothered to format the content in the application itself. If I need to read it, I open de XML in IE (which reads XML better then it does most webpages ;)) or I open it in notepad++ and tidy it with the textFX plugin

Comment: @DanBracuk Your name took me back to 8 years when I used to be very active in Adobe Forums!. I won't forget proactive contributors like you and BKBK :-)  Sorry for being off-topic!

Comment: @Sander actually it's a valid XML file but users would to see a pretty structure of XML when open it using notepad.. when I open it using browser there no problem at all.. finally i just found i need use a function to make a pretty XML print.. thanks for all the reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. actually I just want to make the XML is more readable when opened in notepad. i found function in cflib.org to indent XML and make it become more pretty structure.. :) here the link if someone need it.. 
[indentXML](http://cflib.org/udf/indentXml)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the motivation for making xml documents readable by people, it helps during development.  It makes it easier to ensure that you are matching the tags and data correctly.  Here is an example of something I once did.

First, when you use `cfsavecontent`, line breaks in your source code become part of the variable.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="data">
<BurnRecords>
<cfoutput query="something"> 
more tags and code
</cfoutput>
</BurnRecords>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Next, make it a real xml variable:

```
<cfxml casesensitive="yes" variable="xmldata">
<cfoutput>#Replace(data, chr(10) & chr(13) & chr(10) & chr(13), chr(10), "all")#</cfoutput>
</cfxml>
```

The replace function was because I had too much whitespace.   If you want to read your data as you develop, you can do this:

```
<cfform>
<cftextarea name="x" value="#xmldata#" cols="100" rows="200"></cftextarea>
</cfform>
```

Otherwise, you do this:

```
<cffile action="write" nameconflict="overwrite" file="#FileName#" output="#xmldata#">
```

Comment: Does cftextarea escape the xml? Isn't `xmlformat()` needed?

Comment: For my job at hand, my objective was to look at the data I was producing and the sample code in this answer allowed me to achieve that objecitve.

Comment: actually I just want to make the XML is more readable when opened in notepad. i found function in cflib.org to indent XML and make it become more pretty structure.. :) here the link if someone need it.. 

http://cflib.org/udf/indentXml

Comment: @SudarsonoSung - You should post that as an answer, so it is more visible to the next guy trying to do the same thing.